# How to send email through GWTP

Tags: gwt, gwt-platform

I am developing a web application using gwt and gwtp. 
I can get a list of email address from the server side.

Now I want to send an email to these addresses through server.
Could anyonoe tell me how to do it in gwtp?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not related to `GWTP`. Everything is explained here: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/usingjavamail.html